# Installing eventmachine on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to install eventmachine so I can run this program https://github.com/alexagranov/earnings_date_finder
to see what it does.

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Dakota\Downloads\rails\rails_apps\earnings>ruby script/rails
Could not find eventmachine-0.12.10 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I run 'bundle install' I get this:

```
C:\Users\Dakota\Downloads\rails\rails_apps\earnings>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (0.9.2.2)
Using abstract (1.0.0)
Using activesupport (3.0.11)
Using builder (2.1.2)
Using i18n (0.5.0)

Using activemodel (3.0.11)
Using erubis (2.6.6)
Using rack (1.2.4)
Using rack-mount (0.6.14)
Using rack-test (0.5.7)
Using tzinfo (0.3.31)
Using actionpack (3.0.11)
Using mime-types (1.17.2)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using treetop (1.4.10)
Using mail (2.2.19)
Using actionmailer (3.0.11)
Using arel (2.0.10)
Using activerecord (3.0.11)
Using activeresource (3.0.11)
Using archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Using columnize (0.3.4)
Using daemons (1.1.4)
Installing eventmachine (0.12.10)
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
.

    C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for rb_trap_immediate in ruby.h,rubysig.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/bin/ruby
C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do':
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:546:
in `block in try_compile'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:499:
in `with_werror'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:546:
in `try_compile'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:736:
in `try_var'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1023
:in `block in have_var'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:
in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:
in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:
in `open'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:
in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:
in `open'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:
in `postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:
in `checking_for'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:1022
:in `have_var'
        from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/hgc33_000/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/r
uby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-0.12.10 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/hgc33_000/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/ge
ms/eventmachine-0.12.10/ext/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing eventmachine (0.12.10), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install eventmachine -v '0.12.10'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried many different ways to install eventmachine but every way gives me the same error.

For the record 'gem install eventmachine --pre' gives me this error:

```
C:\Users\Dakota\Downloads\rails\rails_apps\earnings>gem install eventmachine --pre
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing eventmachine:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lssl... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/bin/ruby
        --with-openssl-config
        --without-openssl-config
        --with-pkg-config
        --without-pkg-config
        --with-ssl-dir
        --without-ssl-dir
        --with-ssl-include
        --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
        --with-ssl-lib
        --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/
        --with-ssllib
        --without-ssllib
C:/Users/hgc33_000/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:431:in `try_do':
The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:516:
in `try_link0'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:531:
in `try_link'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:717:
in `try_func'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:947:
in `block in have_library'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:892:
in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:
in `block (2 levels) in postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:
in `open'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:337:
in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:307:
in `open'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:333:
in `postpone'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:891:
in `checking_for'
        from C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/mkmf.rb:942:
in `have_library'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `block in check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `each'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `all?'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `check_libs'
        from extconf.rb:39:in `manual_ssl_config'
        from extconf.rb:61:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/r
uby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/Dakota/Downloads/rails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/ge
ms/eventmachine-1.0.3/ext/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install build-essential` and then `bundle install`

Answer (score 6):

I could install it, doing this steps:

1) tried a normal install:

```
gem install eventmachine
```

it fetched the version 1.0.3 of the gem, but failed in the make, because of a variable declaration conflit

2) edited the file:

```
c:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.0.3\ext\project.h
```

and commented the line 97

```
//typedef int pid_t;
```

3) then, i've opened command prompt, and went to the gem folder

```
c:\Ruby200-x64\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.0.3
```

and runned:

```
gem build eventmachine.gemspec
```

4) it generated a eventmachine.gem file on the folder... So I've copied a file to a c:\tmp folder, and went to that folder and from there, I've typed:

```
gem install eventmachine-1.0.3.gem --local
```

And it installed successfully!

Comment: I just started gem install, and while it was compiling I opened project.h, commented line 97 and saved.

Comment: worked for me, thanks. In order to run `gem build eventmachine.gemspec`, for some reason I had to run a `git init` because it was giving  me an error `fatal: not a git repository....`

Comment: Step 3 says here: C:\Ruby\lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.0.3>gem build eventmachine.gemspec
Invalid gemspec in [eventmachine.gemspec]: No such file or directory - git ls-files
ERROR:  Error loading gemspec. Aborting.

Comment: @JuniorMayhé you'll need to have git installed to get the build to complete successfully

Answer (score 0):

Found you via Reddit!

Try using the precompiled **eventmachine** gem

`gem install eventmachine --pre`

You're getting this issue because the eventmachine gem (or one of it's dependencies) is written in C and needs to be compiled by a locally available C compiler (LLVM, GCC, etc).

If you continue to get this issue after including the `--pre` flag in your gemfile, I would uninstall all local eventmachine versions and take a look at these links:

1. [eventmachine issue #411](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/pull/411)
2. [issue #217](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/issues/217)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After following Fera's steps.
Yes it now did install with message

```
Successfully installed eventmachine-1.0.3
1 gem installed
```

but not usable.

in \lib\ruby\gems\2.0.0\gems\eventmachine-1.0.3\ext
there was an error in mkmf.log and nothing was actually build

```
package configuration for openssl is not found
have_library: checking for main() in -lssl... -------------------- no
```